# How do I see if dates came before or after with javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm given a date `const date1 = "2020-08-08"`

I want to check whether this date is before today or after today

```
const date1 = "2020-08-08"
const today = new Date()
if(date1 > new Date) {
    console.log("date1 is the future")
} else {
    console.log("date1 is the past")
}
```

The above code doesn't work but I am trying to do something like that. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using getTime()

```
var date1 = new Date(2020 - 08 - 08);
var today = new Date();  
if (date1.getTime() > today.getTime()) {
  // Date 1 is the Future
} else {
  // Today is the Future
}
```

or you can compare directly like `date1 > today`

If you have date as string , then parse using ,

```
var date1 = Date.parse("2020-08-08");
```

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. It shouldn't contain syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract today and compare:

```
var now = new Date();
var month = (now.getMonth() + 1);               
var day = now.getDate();
if (month < 10) 
    month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10) 
    day = "0" + day;
var year = now.getFullYear();
var today = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
```

You can compare year, month and day separately and see.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working snippet to get you started:

```js
let date1 = Date.parse("2020-08-08");
let today = new Date();

if (date1 < today) {
  console.log("Date1 is in the past");
} else {
  console.log("Date1 is in the future");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date-fns` library for date comparisions.

https://date-fns.org/v2.15.0/docs/isBefore

https://date-fns.org/v2.15.0/docs/isAfter

```js
isAfter(date1, today);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `if (date1 > new Date)` the expression *new Date* returns a string, so you're effectively comparing `'2020-08-08' > new Date().toString()`. Since both operands are strings, they will be compared lexically and since the lefthand string starts with a number and the righthand string will always start with a letter, the result will always be false.

What you probably mean to do is:

```
const date1 = "2020-08-08";
const today = new Date();
if (date1 > today) {
    console.log("date1 is the future");
}
```

However, '2020-08-08' will be parsed as UTC, so on 8 August the test may return true or false depending on the host system offset setting and the time that the code is executed. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)